# What is most efficient way to solve $A^{1/2} x = b$?

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra, numerical-optimization

Given $A$ a $n\times n$ real symmetric positive semidefinite matrix,  $b$ a vector of dimension $n$. What is the most efficiently way to solve the linear system
$$
A^{\frac12} x = b
$$

I know the basic way which consists of doing an eigenvalue decomposition of $A$ first, and then take square-root of the diagonal matrix and finally solve the linear system. This basic way has a complexity of $O(n^3)$.

Is it possible to do better with any other practical implementations?

Comment: There are several other ways to compute the square root of a matrix: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_a_matrix maybe one can be faster in your situation.

Comment: It is impossible to answer your question without information about the sparsity and structure of your matrix as well as information about your computer. Even if the matrix is dense, then it can be faster to first reduce the matrix to an intermediate banded form before reducing it further to tridiagonal form and finally to diagonal form. It will depend on your machine. Rounding errors may also perturb the eigenvalues so that some present as strictly negative. While there is a significant overlap between the two communities, I recommend that you post your question on sci.comp.stackexhange

Comment: Thanks, I did not know about sci.comp.stackexhange.

Answer (score 1):

Common approaches to this problem include:

- Lanczos iteration
- Eigendecompsoition
- Cholesky/LDL factorization (depending on how you define $A^{1/2}$ or if $b$ is a spherically symmetric random vector)

Among these methods, Lanczos has the advantage of being "matrix free" and requiring very little storage. It is also iterative, and therefore allows you to trade time for accuracy. The downside is that the iteration must be run again if you have a new vector $b$. On the other hand, the factorization based approaches can be applied to many vectors efficiently after the factorization is computer.

Perhaps less common approaches include

- sketching A to get a low-rank approximation
- rational Krylov methods

Comment: I get Lanczos iteration for computing matrix power. Do you have a reference for Lanczos for computing matrix square root? Thanks!

Comment: here are some slides: https://www.chrismusco.com/stableLanczos60.pdf. You might also look at Chapter 13 of Higham's book on matrix functions which has some more references